# Substitute read only property in partially mocked object

Tags: c#, unit-testing, mocking, nsubstitute

I'm testing an MVC controller which relies on a value returned from a read-only property on the base class.

The getter for this property throws an exception when it is called as it is relies on a `HttpContext` (and other nasty stuff) which I would rather avoid mocking.

This is what I've tried so far:

```
controller = Substitute.ForPartsOf<MyController>(
    Substitute.For<SomeDependency>(),
);

controller.UserInfo.Returns(new UserInfo());
```

Yet this throws an exception as soon as UserInfo is accessed.

Property on base class is:

```
public UserInfo UserInfo
{
    get
    {
        // HttpContext dependent stuff
    }
}
```

I've tried setting the base class property to virtual but then I get a Castle proxy exception.

Comment: Can you add a dependency to `MyController` that accesses `UserInfo` and related stuff? At test time pass in a `FakeUserInfoProvider` and at run time use a `HttpContextUserInfoProvider`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think you may be having another problem. NSubstitute is capable of handling substitution of virtual properties. Here is a small program that illustrates

```
public class SubstitutedClass
{
    public virtual int SubstitutedProperty { get { throw new InvalidOperationException(); }  }
}

internal class Program
{
    private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var test2 = Substitute.For<SubstitutedClass>();
        test2.SubstitutedProperty.Returns(10);
        Console.WriteLine(test2.SubstitutedProperty);
    }
}
```

**EDIT:** Regarding your use of `ForPartsOf` I don't think it is possible to override a property this way, since there is no way of informing NSubstitute that we don't want it to call the base code. That's why the documentation mentions that partial sub are [not recommended](http://nsubstitute.github.io/help/partial-subs/)

You could change the base class in order to return the value of a virtual function; this virtual function would then be substituted. No signature change for the callers. Although this is a hack you would get what you need

```
public class SubstitutedClass
{
    public virtual int SubstitutedProperty { get { return InnerValue(); } }
    public virtual int InnerValue() { throw new InvalidOperationException(); }
}

var test2 = Substitute.ForPartsOf<SubstitutedClass>();
test2.When(t => t.InnerValue()).DoNotCallBase();
test2.InnerValue().Returns(10);
```

Comment: What about the partial mock `ForPartsOf`?

Comment: @BenFoster Indeed, I hadn't seen the ForPartsOf method, which doesn't work in this case. Looking into it

Comment: @BenFoster edited my answer to add some information regarding `ForPartsOf`

Comment: Thanks, the fact that `ForPartsOf` still executes the original property code was the problem. Since I couldn't change the base class I just ended up mocking `ControllerContext`.